# WebUSB descriptor for STM32F767

Tags: c, stm32, webusb, stm32f7

I tried to debug to see if a request is being made with the vendor ID of 0x02, but I don't get any device request for the URL:

```
USBD_StatusTypeDef USBD_StdDevReq(USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev, USBD_SetupReqTypedef *req)
{
    USBD_StatusTypeDef ret = USBD_OK;

    switch (req->bmRequest & USB_REQ_TYPE_MASK)
    {
        case USB_REQ_TYPE_CLASS:
        case USB_REQ_TYPE_VENDOR:
            ret = (USBD_StatusTypeDef)pdev->pClass[pdev->classId]->Setup(pdev, req);
            break;

        case USB_REQ_TYPE_STANDARD:
            switch (req->bRequest)
            {
                case USB_REQ_GET_DESCRIPTOR:
                case 0x02:
                USBD_GetDescriptor(pdev, req);
                break;
```